# Easy way to view data in pgAdmin (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have searched this problem for more than an hour without any clue. In Heidi SQL (for MySQL), I just need few clicks to open any table to view its data. But in pgAdmin, I **must collapse many sub-folder to do that**: database/Schemas/public/Tables/... and then I must right click on a table to "view data". It's 3 times slower.

I wonder if there is any easier way to look through PostgreSQL data? Or is there any other way for Postgres that allow me to make it faster?

Comment: I can't believe now it's 2021, 10 years has passed and still I have to go through so many steps just to view data in pgAdmin !

Comment: It really is. However I have switched to Heidi SQL since now they support PostGres as well :)

Comment: Tried to try HeidiSQL today, and just realized that it's only for Windows not Mac. So I found TablePlus. Not bad for browsing data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the properties of your server and check the "restore env" checkbox. That option causes pgadmin to remember your navigation between sessions. It will take you right to the table you selected last time you used pgadmin.

Comment: thanks, though it's checked by default. But I still need to right-click, and navigate to "View Data/View 100 rows"? Is there any elegant way to do that?

Comment: On the toolbar is an icon that looks like a grid.  Click it to view the data in the selected table.

Comment: Now I realize Ctrl-D or Ctrl-G work too. It should be more user-friendly for such a good DBMS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. There has got to be a better workflow. By comparison with, say phpMyAdmin, this is pretty bad. Are we missing something?

Comment: PGAdmin's design is laughably bad.  I've never seen such an absurd or complex way to present basic data to people.

99% of users don't care about materialized views or foreign_key constraints: they just want to see what data they have in their tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up an ODBC connection to the database, you can access it in Microsoft Access. You can then add the tables you view most often (assuming they're not so many of them) and save them (linked rather than copied) for quick viewing and editing.