# Viewing data graphically in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I've been trying to figure how postgresql works for the last couple of days. There's something I don't get. Is there a way to see the data inside the tables graphically? Something similar to MySQL's phpMyadmin? Or can I only see the data by querying it?

Comment: Ok i found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892222/easy-way-to-view-data-in-pgadmin-postgresql

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pgadmin3. http://www.pgadmin.org/

If you are using a package manager on your machine like `MacPorts`, you can also download it using `sudo port install pgadmin3`.

Here are some example screenshots which will guide you to find where you can select "View Data".

[image]

Make sure your are connected to your postgresql server and the specific database you are interested in.

Then click into its hierarchy to open up `public`, which will contain another group named `Tables`, like this:-

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. I'm running pgadminIII already. But I clicked everything I could click and still haven't been able to find my data.

Comment: Woah dude, thanks. Didn't need to go through all that trouble.

Comment: :-)    It was a quick thing. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free program called `pgAdmin` that you can download from [pgadmin.org](http://www.pgadmin.org/).